# How to mock a method in the very same service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-service, karma-jasmine

I have a service like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('myService', function() {

    var a = function() {
        return b();
    }

    function b() {
        return 'foo';
    }

    return {
        a: a
    };
});
```

Now, I want to test `a();` by mocking `b();`, e.g. by making it return *bar*. My test would be like this:

```
it('should call a() and return string bar', function() {
    // mock function b() here
    expect(myService.a()).toBe('bar');
});
```

How can I mock `b();` in this case? I was thinking about using [`$provide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide) but it seems to work for [`$inject`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector) only.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **spyOn**. Here is an example:

```
beforeEach(function(){
    spyOn(myService, 'b').and.returnValue('bar');
});

it('should call a() and return string bar', function() {
    expect(myService.a()).toBe('bar');
});
```

Read more about spying here http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I forgot to mention that `b();` is not being returned by the *service*. Is this still achievable by using *spies*? I've updated my question.

Comment: Can you use `spyOn(myService, 'b').and.returnValue('bar');` without initiating `myService` in the `describe()` block and `myService = {b: function(value) {}};`? Beacuse then it would mock the whole service, including `a();`

Comment: No you can't I assumed you have had it initialized. About your previous question unfortunatelly i do not know.